# TikZ split rectangle into 2

Tags: tikz-trees, tikz-shape

I am drawing a picture where I have nodes of different shapes and colors. For elliptical nodes, I get 2 halves as expected, but for rectangular ones I obtain 4 parts. The lower part text is not displayed. I cannot understand why. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes} 
\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}[plain]
       \maketitle
   \end{frame}
   
   \begin{frame}
       \frametitle{sth}
       \begin{figure}
           \tikzset{
               attacker/.style = {
                   color = red,
                   shape = ellipse split,
                   text  = black},
               defender/.style = {
                   color = green,
                   shape = rectangle split,
                   text  = black}
           }
           \begin{tikzpicture}[
           every node/.style = {
               draw, 
               text width = },
           grow = down, 
           level 1/.style = {sibling distance=2cm},
           level 2/.style = {sibling distance=1cm},
           level distance = 2.5cm,
           ]
           \node[attacker] (Goal) {X \nodepart{lower} {$\vee$}} 
               child { node[defender] (partition) {Y \nodepart{lower}{$\wedge$}}
               };
           \end{tikzpicture}
       \end{figure}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Sorry, but but code has many issues:

- for multipart shapes you should load `tikz` library `shapes.multipart`
- `rectangle split` has not defined `\nodepart{lower}`. You should define how many parts has and in which part you like to have text (`\vedge`)
- to have `tikzset` inside of frame, frame had to have option `fragile`

I guess that you after the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{sth}
\begin{figure}
\tikzset{
   attacker/.style = {
       color = red,
       shape = ellipse split,
       text  = black},
   defender/.style = {
       color = green,
       shape = rectangle split,
       rectangle split parts=#1,
       text  = black}
        }
   \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {draw},
             grow = down,
   level 1/.style = {sibling distance=2cm},
   level 2/.style = {sibling distance=1cm},
   level distance = 2.5cm,
                        ]
\node[attacker] (Goal) {X \nodepart{lower} {$\vee$}}
    child { node[defender=2] (partition) {Y \nodepart{two}{$\wedge$}} };
           \end{tikzpicture}
       \end{figure}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However it is not clear why for this simple image you usee `tree` construct ...

**Edit:**
As I mentioned in y comment (as response on yours),  `rectangle split` has not defined `lower` part. You need to explicitly say in which part (exception for the first part, where this is not obligated, but it will not harm, if you declare it explicitly as `text` or `one`) is node content. So what you like to do, is not possible.

However, if you like for some reason use only two part `multipart` shape, where the second part you like to name `lower`, the closet what you can do is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\newcommand\Lower{\nodepart{two}}% you should be aware, 
                                 % that`lower` is already defined in `tikz`

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{sth}
\begin{figure}
\tikzset{
   attacker/.style = {
       color = red,
       shape = ellipse split,
       text  = black},
   defender/.style = {
       color = green,
       shape = rectangle split,
       rectangle split parts=2,
       text  = black}
        }
   \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {draw},
             grow = down,
   level 1/.style = {sibling distance=2cm},
   level 2/.style = {sibling distance=1cm},
   level distance = 2.5cm,
                        ]
\node[attacker] (Goal) {X \nodepart{lower} {$\vee$}}
    child { node[defender] (partition) {Y \Lower $\wedge$} };
           \end{tikzpicture}
       \end{figure}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result is as before.

Comment: Note also that `\nodepart` only has one argument (the part you want to switch to), so here `Y \nodepart{two}$\wedge$` is sufficient. I know this was in the original code but it's another small point for improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. As to your question, I removed a large part of my figure to get a MWE. One further question from me: where have I implicitly defined that "attacker" nodes must have a lower part?

Comment: @mushishi, as I said in answer, `rectangle split` has not defined `lower` part, You need to say in which part (exception for the first part, where this is not obligated, but it will not harm, if you declare it explicitly as `text` or `one`) is content. So what you like to do, is not possible. However you can define new command with similar name (not the same!!!). See edited answer (will appear soon)