# How to inner split tikz rectangle by half with different colors?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using following solution [How to split tikz rectangle by half with different colors and text lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301406/127048). On top of this solution is it possible to split a row into two and color it differently?

`@Torbjørn T.` solution from the linked answer:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\tikzset{
state/.style={
       rectangle split,
       rectangle split parts=2,
       rectangle split part fill={red!30,blue!20},
       rounded corners,
       draw=black, very thick,
       minimum height=2em,
       text width=3cm,
       inner sep=2pt,
       text centered,
       }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [state] {text\\txet \nodepart{two} blue background \\ here};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

wanted output:

```
|-----|-------|
| red | white |
|-----|-------|
|    blue     |
|_____________|
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't just post code fragments. Always make a compilable minimal working example as starting point.

Comment: Sorry fixed I try to add quote to code piece which messed up its format

Comment: Here are 2 threads that seem to deal with this question: 1 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152292/split-a-node-into-3-parts and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651710/tikz-split-rectangle-into-2
link number one is  the most suitable IMO

Comment: @anis first linked thread does not use rectangle split

Comment: @alper is using rectangle split that crucial for you?

Comment: @anis yes sir its easier to coordinate arrows starting points on rectangle split when there are multiple rows inside rectangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @anis answer, but code reproduce in question showed image:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                positioning}
    
\begin{document}
     \tikzset{
sectors/.style n args={8}{minimum width=#1, minimum height=#2, 
                          text depth=0.25ex, outer sep=0pt,
                          append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
    \draw[fill=#3]  (\LN.west)  -| (\LN.north)
                    {[rounded corners=3mm] -- (\LN.north west)}
                                |- cycle;
%
    \draw[fill=#5]  (\LN.north)  |- (\LN.east)
                    {[rounded corners=3mm] -- (\LN.north east)}
                                -- cycle;
%
    \draw[fill=#7]  (\LN.west)  {[rounded corners=3mm] |- (\LN.south east)} 
                                |- cycle;
    \path   (\LN.center) -- node[align=center] {#4} (\LN.north west) 
            (\LN.center) -- node[align=center] {#6} (\LN.north east) 
            (\LN.center) -- node[align=center] {#8} (\LN.south);
                     } } }
                }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [sectors= {32mm}{24mm}
                    {red!30}{text\\ text}
                    {white}{Disk}
                    {blue!30}{blue bacground\\ here}] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

However, I suspect that you looking for general building blocks (BB), by which you can to compose any blocks structure:

- Is this is a case, you should be aware that splitting of nodes to subnodes is very hard task.
- Far more simple is connect nodes (BB), tight to each other, in desired connections.
- In this is drawing further simpler, if nodes shapes are rectangles with sharp corners (than is sufficient to define only one BB),
- For further/better help,  please show us an example of structure(s) which you like to draw.
- Below is an example of composition with simple building blocks of rectangle shape:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
     \tikzset{
 node distance = 0pt,
BB/.style args={#1/#2/#3}{% Building Box, options
        draw, semithick, 
        font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont, align=center, 
        minimum width=#1, minimum height=#2, text depth=0.25ex, 
        fill=#3, outer sep=0pt}
            } % end of tikzset
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (L1)  [BB=32mm/8mm/teal!30] {basic layer};
    \node (L2)  [BB=32mm/8mm/yellow!30,
                 above=of L1] {second layer};
    \node (L31) [BB=16mm/12mm/red!30,
                 above right=of L2.north west] {third\\ level\\ first};
    \node (L32) [BB=16mm/12mm/orange!30,
                 right=of L31] {third\\ level\\ second};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my adaptation of this solution:
[How create circle node in Tikz with T from lines inside? T made split node to 3 sectors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58993/how-create-circle-node-in-tikz-with-t-from-lines-inside-t-made-split-node-to-3)

I just added rectangles to fill the space inside the node.
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \tikzset{sectors/.style n args={6}{%
            rectangle,
            draw,
            minimum width=#4,
            minimum height=#5,
            append after command={%
                \pgfextra{ %
                    \draw (\tikzlastnode.center) -- (\tikzlastnode.south) ;
                    \draw (\tikzlastnode.west)   -- (\tikzlastnode.east) ;
                    \draw[fill = blue] (\tikzlastnode.west) rectangle (\tikzlastnode.north east);  
                    \path (\tikzlastnode.center) -- node[#6] {#1} (\tikzlastnode.north); 
                    
                    \draw[fill = cyan] (\tikzlastnode.center) rectangle (\tikzlastnode.south west);  
                    \path (\tikzlastnode.center) -- node[#6] {#2} (\tikzlastnode.south west); 
                    
                    \draw[fill = green] (\tikzlastnode.center) rectangle (\tikzlastnode.south east);  
                    \path (\tikzlastnode.center) -- node[#6] {#3} (\tikzlastnode.south east);
                 } }}}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
    \node [sectors={1}{2}{3}{5cm}{5cm}{font=\Huge\bfseries,text=red}]  (c)  {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: What should I do if there are 3 rows?